# Can't get a span on the same line - Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a title `<h1>`, and a word in it has a custom style which I define in my separate CSS file. Therefore I wrap this word inside a `<span>`, but then I can't get it to remain on the same line. I have tried flex-nowrap, inline-flex, inline-block, but those don't work.

Result:

[image: result]

The expected output:

[image: expected result]

I have tried flex-nowrap, inline-flex, inline-block, chat gpt, Tailwind documentation.

```html
<header className="max-w-[1420px] mx-auto pb-[130px] flex flex-col lg:pl-[240px] py-[50px] space-x-1  lg:flex-row relative items-center [&_*]:text-white w-full">
  <div className="flex w-[80vw] lg:w-[70vw]">
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
      <h1 class="tracking-[1px] w-[100%] text-center lg:text-left mx-auto -mt-10_disabled lg:mt-0 text-white_disabled lg:w-[534px] text-[35px] lg:text-[55px] mb-2 font-extrabold whitespace-normal lg:whitespace-nowrap">
        A Safe place <br /> to join the
        <span class="gradient-text inline-block lg:inline-block tracking-[1px] text-[37px] lg:text-[57px] whitespace-nowrap">
          &nbsp;best
        </span>
              <span class="text-white_disabled inline-block text-[35px] lg:text-[55px] mb-2 font-extrabold whitespace-nowrap">
          .
        </span>
      </h1>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: is this not just related to the size of screen? you state the problem but around 281px the font size will wrap the row anyways, a way around it is to use "w-max"

Comment: Hmm I don't think so, it should look exactly the same on every screen anyway

Comment: this is what I am talking about: https://play.tailwindcss.com/0BkqvXMSS9?size=280x720

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for trying to help :) I ended up finding a solution to my issue! Here it is: I wrapped each elements in spans then set my parent container h1 to flex, flex-nowrap and here it is. I left the br/ where I wanted it and it works. Not moving on any screen sizes.

```
<h1 className="tracking-[1px] flex flex-col justify-center lg:justify-start w-[100%] text-center lg:text-left mx-auto -mt-10 lg:mt-0 text-white lg:w-[534px] text-[35px] lg:text-[55px] mb-2 font-extrabold whitespace-normal lg:whitespace-nowrap">
            <span>A Safe place</span>
            <div className="flex flex-nowrap justify-center lg:justify-start whitespace-nowrap">
              <span>to join the</span>
              <span className="gradient-text font-extrabold tracking-[1px] pr-1 whitespace-nowrap text-[35px] lg:text-[55px]">
                &nbsp;best
              </span>
              <span className="text-white text-[35px] lg:text-[55px] mb-2 font-extrabold whitespace-nowrap">
                .
              </span>
            </div>
          </h1>
```